# Is it possible to have multi realm security with the Grails Spring Security Plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security, shiro

I have found a few examples of how spring security itself supports the ability to use different authentication mechanisms for different url patterns. A likely use case is where you want to distinguish between browser authentication and RESTful API key authentication depending on the url. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/spring-security-two-security-realms-in.html

Today we use two grails apps to accomplish this separation. I have seen shiro plugin has the concepts of realms but would like to know if its possible to accomplish this with the Spring Sec Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

From further research I believe employing a [filter chain map](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/filters.html) it's possible to assign a specific filter for particular URLs so a new filter can be created to handle rest requests.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
        '/web/**': 'WEBFILTER1,filter2,filter3,filter4',
        '/rest/**': 'RESTFILTER1,filter3,filter5',
        '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS',
]
```